# Consider the matrix {1, -1; 1 -1}. If I multiply first row by -1, it loses the total unimodular property.

Tags: matrices, unimodular-matrices

Seymor says that multiplying a row by -1 preserves total unimodularity. Please explain this fallacy.

Comment: I'm sorry. There is no fallacy.

Comment: Apologies for wasting time. Please delete my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiplying the matrix by $-1$, we obtain

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Clearly, every $1$ by $1$ matrix is unimodular and the matrix itself is singular. Hence it is still totally unimodular.